# Flash page failed to load in google chrome in Linux, works fine in Windows7

Tags: google-chrome, flash, ubuntu-16.04

I am using **google-chrome-stable** (Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit)) on Ubuntu 16.04. I regularly update my system. Recently when I am going to load a page with flash application getting the following error

[image]

followed by

[image]

The details of flash plugin in my system,

[image]

---

#### Note:

- I can watch youtube or facebook video without any issue.
- Pages like `http://www.hotstar.com/` or `http://www.speedtest.net/` fails to load.
- In windows 7 I have no such issue even with lower version (23.0.0.162) of flash in Mozilla Firefox.

Is the problem really with update? or something else. How do I resolve the issue of Adobe flash plugin in google chrome in Ubuntu?

Comment: It is out of date https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/flash-player/apsb16-36.html but I don't think Google have issued a Chrome update yet.

Comment: @DavidMarshall thank you for your effort, I don't think that is the only problem. Otherwise without the update (Google have not issued yet) nobody could watch a page with flash. right?

Comment: Some things to check here https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784?hl=en-GB